# Why does Visual Studio need to run as administrator to publish to local IIS?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web-deployment

Why does Visual Studio require administrative privileges to publish to local IIS? Does it need the permissions to bind a port, or is it because it copies files to a directory owned by a different user?

I'm talking about the "Please launch Visual Studio under administrator mode to perform this deployment action" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio uses IIS APIs (varied based on operating systems) to perform deployment tasks. Such APIs are designed to be called only by administrators, so VS is forced to ask you for that permission in turn. So the things you mentioned (bindings, file system access) are all related, but only part of the whole image.

I am cloning `Microsoft.Web.Administration` (one of the IIS APIs), so I can fully understand why they desire administrator permissions initially, which does make implementation simple enough.

Comment: Did you end up reading Microsoft's code? Any insights?

Comment: @G.Stoynev No. I never have access to IIS source code (even though I worked and am working for Microsoft). There are enough books and public documentation on how the configuration system works, so not that difficult to write a similar implementation based on Linq to XML, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/tree/v13.0.23.0/Microsoft.Web.Administration